# Unable to install Windows 10 next to Ubuntu: GPT error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, gpt, mbr

I have Ubuntu installed, but I need a Windows next to it. I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.techsolveprac.com/install-windows-after-ubuntu-dual/) to do so, but when I reach the screen where I'm supposed to choose the space for Win I'm getting an error: "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style" [(screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gAiU.png).

Of course I've tried to change the partition style, by following another guide. Currently, gdisk results for the
drive are saying that it's MBR only and GPT is not present: [gdisk results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AlRJ.png)

I've tried to create a Win pendrive with Rufus (with both MBR and GPT settings), but then I'm getting error "Windows cannot find the Microsoft license software terms" error afer entering the Win license key.

I'm stuck, no idea how to do it other than formatting the drive and installing Win and then Ubuntu, but this I'd rather avoid, as I don't want to format an SSD and it's a lot of work to install back all the stuff on the Ubuntu.

Comment: I suspect your Windows installation media is invalid. Make sure you are booting the USB as UEFI. (Check your BIOS settings). Be prepared for the possibility of Windows to screw up GRUB.  You'll probably need to do an `os-prober` and `update-grub` when you're done

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs for both Ubuntu & Windows. Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives & only in BIOS mode to MBR drives. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI mode since 2012. So boot Windows installer in UEFI mode. If Windows was originally on system, the product key is in UEFI & can cannot be used with BIOS.

Comment: There never was Windows on this machine, I have my own copy. I'll try doubly checking the boot options, thanks.

Comment: @Nmath and oldfred, that was the thing, I feel quite silly now. Thanks A LOT. It's my first question here, so I don't know the customs. Can you post the comment as the answer so that I could mark it?

Comment: Yes, so I want rep for you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You should've install windows first then ubuntu. It is way comfier. Anyways. I think you can just create Volume using gparted or Disks and install windows there through Windows Setup

Comment: So I need two pendrives, one with Ubuntu and one with Windows simultaneously and run the Win install from try Ubuntu? I've already created free, unallocated space with gparted. And I know that installing Win first would have been much better, but original plan was Ubuntu only.

Comment: If you installed ubuntu in UEFI mode then yes. Just Resize main partition using ubuntu live on a usb stick. And then boot windows setup and install it there. If you have Legacy well oops

Comment: Advice from Nmath comment worked out, so I can't tell if your would work as well (I didn't have two usb sticks to try it out).

Comment: You dont need 2 usb sticks